# What is the Seventh-Day Adventist view of hell?

Tags: hell, seventh-day-adventists

While listening to a video of "Ready to Harvest" (a great neutral viewpoint denomination YouTube channel), he said something very briefly that made it sound like Seventh-Day Adventists don't believe in hell, which I wasn't aware of, I was only aware of their view of soul sleep.

So for clarification, what is the SDA view of hell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Seventh Day Adventists believe that 'hell' describes the finite suffering of sinners which results in their destruction

The SDA church believes that upon death, souls enter a period of sleep preceding judgement day. On judgement day, there will be an undefined but *not* infinite period period of suffering for sinners which is not the traditional eternal hell, but rather the fires of destruction. Citing passages like Matthew 13:49 to the effect that hell is a destroying furnace, they also [claim](https://adventistguide.com/adventists-hell/) that:

> The book of Malachi states that sinners will only burn until there is nothing left to burn.

The SDA church discounts references to '*eternal* destruction' in the bible by pointing to the metaphorical uses of 'forever'. Their views are specifically set up against historic Christian beliefs which they view as lies meant to scare people into attending church.

Comment: So are they annihalationists?

Comment: Haven't seen them use the term, and most annihilationists believe unbelievers are destroyed, whereas SDA seem to take descriptions of hell as somewhat literal, i.e. there is a process of torment which destroys unbelievers. Thus they are not what is commonly understood to be "annihilationists" although they espouse a form of annihilationism

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks and +1 plus accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

SDAs are Annihilationists from their [statement of faith](https://www.adventist.org/beliefs/):

> "The unrighteous dead will then be resurrected, and with Satan and his angels will surround the city; but fire from God will consume them and cleanse the earth.

> The universe will thus be freed of sin and sinners forever."

All of their pioneers believed in annihilationist, that the dead will be burnt up. They believe in hellfire but that it occurs as a punishment after the 1000 years in heaven are finished. So they believe people will burn just not a never ending burning.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).